# Не могу установить Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Установил `Java 1.8.0`. Не могу установить `Eclipse`. Логи установки:

```
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Executing bootstrap tasks
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_102-b14
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.android.neon
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.5.0.v20160818-1158, build=2601, branch=bdf2ff7581fb0b3481aab45845b009448eb9c2e6
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.5.0.v20160913-0854, build=2601, branch=bdf2ff7581fb0b3481aab45845b009448eb9c2e6
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.5.0.v20160707-0243, build=2601, branch=bdf2ff7581fb0b3481aab45845b009448eb9c2e6
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Performing P2 Director (Eclipse for Android Developers (Neon))
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Offline = false
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Mirrors = true
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Resolving 27 requirements from 3 repositories to C:\Users\Semyon\Documents\android-neon2\eclipse
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement epp.package.android [4.6.0,4.7.0)
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.6.0,4.7.0)
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.6.0,4.7.0)
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.andmore.android.basic.feature.feature.group
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.andmore.gldebugger.feature.feature.group
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.andmore.hierarchyviewer.feature.feature.group
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.andmore.ndk.feature.feature.group
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.andmore.traceview.feature.feature.group
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.feature.group
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla_feature.feature.group
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature.feature.group
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.git.feature.group
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.hudson.feature.group
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.ide_feature.feature.group
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.java_feature.feature.group
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.mylyn.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.snipmatch.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Requirement org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/neon
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon
[2016-10-10 22:57:14] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2016-10-10 22:57:16] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository code=1002 Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon.
ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository code=0 An error occurred while downloading http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/neon/content.xml.xz. The cache file C:\Users\Semyon\.p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository\cache\downloading\2079680757 could not be renamed to C:\Users\Semyon\.p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository\cache\2079680757.
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.updateCache(CacheManager.java:428)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.createCacheFromFile(CacheManager.java:132)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.getLocalFile(XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:56)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(XZedSimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:78)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:116)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:386)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:193)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Metadata.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:453)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepository.addChild(CompositeMetadataRepository.java:166)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepository.<init>(CompositeMetadataRepository.java:106)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(CompositeMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:122)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:116)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:386)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:193)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Metadata.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:453)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$RepositoryLoader$Worker.perform(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:1613)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.WorkerPool$Worker.run(WorkerPool.java:416)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

[2016-10-10 22:57:16]
```

Сама ошибка:

```
ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository code=0 An error occurred while downloading 
 http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/neon/content.xml.xz.   
 The cache file C:\Users\Semyon\.p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository
 \cache\downloading\2079680757 could not be renamed to C:\Users\Semyon
 \.p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository\cache\2079680757.
```

Comment: Какой конкретно Eclipse? Там сборок же навалом.

Comment: Вообще на нескольких сборках пробовал. Всё то же самое. Пробовал сборку для Android приложений. Устанавливаю через этот инсталлятор https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/neon/R1/eclipse-inst-win64.exe

Comment: А что значит "установить"? Я всё тупо распаковываю в нужную папку, что под виндами, что под линуксом, безо всяких установщиков... А потом уже через Help->Install New Software добиваю нужным.

Comment: Я так понял, установщик скачивает пакеты. Попробую так и сделать, т.е. скачать и закинуть вручную.

Comment: возможно у них проблемы с p2 neon. Попробуйте установить Mars или Oxygen

Comment: Вот тут [как установить Eclipse Neon](http://pr0soft.blogspot.ru/2016/07/eclipse-neon-46.html) в картинках :)

Answer (score 1):

Удалите папку C:\Users\Semyon.p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository\cache эклипс не может получить доступ к её содержимому по каким-то причинам.

Answer (score 0):

Вот три пакета, устанавливаем и работаем.

1. Install Java Development Kit
   Download and install latest version of [Java Development Kit (JDK)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
2. Install Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
   Download an install [Eclipse Integrated Development Environment (IDE) for Java Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/mars2).
3. Install Android Development Tools
   Install the Eclipse Plugin: [Android Development Tools (ADT)](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html).